# pywraplp best way to view constraints

Tags: python, linear-programming

I am using pywraplp to build a linear program, and I am wondering what is the best way to view the constraints after creating? I know there is prob.constraints(), but I want to be able to see a list of all constraints like below. Is there a function that can accomplish this? Thanks

```
x[0] + 3 x[1] < 10
x[1] + 3 x[2] - 4 x[3] > 15
```